# How to interpolate between fixed values in a 2D grid for biome-generation?

Tags: rust, interpolation, procedural-generation, bilinear-interpolation

I am currently implementing biome-generation in my game and I want to make the type of a biome dependent on `humidity` and `temperature` values that are generated from gradual noise.

different Biomes should have different heights and without interpolation this would result in abrupt height differences on biome borders as expected.

What I tried was to get the 2 neighbour biomes in the grid too and measure the blend-percentage of each biome.

Later I then get the 3 different `height` values from the biomes and multiply each with it's respective `blend` value.

Here is the simplified and stripped code, which I use to fetch biomes:

```rs
const BIOME_GRID_SIZE: usize = 2;
const BIOME_INDEX_SIZE: usize = BIOME_GRID_SIZE - 1;
const BIOME_GRID: [[Biomes; BIOME_GRID_SIZE]; BIOME_GRID_SIZE] =
    [
        [Biomes::Mountains, Biomes::Forest],
        [Biomes::Desert   , Biomes::Mesa  ],
    ];

fn get_height(coord: [i64; 2], noise: &Noise) -> i64 {
    let temperature = (noise.get_2d(coord) + 0.5).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    let humidity = (noise.get_2d(coord /* + some offset */) + 0.5).clamp(0.0, 1.0);

    let x = BIOME_GRID_SIZE as f64 * humidity;
    let y = BIOME_GRID_SIZE as f64 * temperature;

    let x_frac = (x.fract() - 0.5) * 2.0;
    let y_frac = (y.fract() - 0.5) * 2.0;
    let x_blending = x_frac.abs();
    let y_blending = y_frac.abs();
    let own_blending = 2.0 - x_blending - y_blending;

    // direction of neighbour biomes
    let x_direction = x_frac.signum() as isize;
    let y_direction = y_frac.signum() as isize;

    let x_index = (x.trunc() as isize).clamp(0, BIOME_INDEX_SIZE as isize);
    let y_index = (y.trunc() as isize).clamp(0, BIOME_INDEX_SIZE as isize);
    let biomes = get_biomes(x_index, y_index, x_direction, y_direction);

    blend(
        coord,
        noise,
        biomes,
        [
            own_blending,
            x_blending,
            y_blending,
        ]
    ),
}

// get main and neighbour biomes
fn get_biomes(x: isize, y: isize, x_direction: isize, y_direction: isize) -> [Biomes; 3] {
    let mut biomes = [Biomes::Ocean; 3];

    for (i, (d_x, d_y)) in [(0, 0), (x_direction, 0), (0, y_direction)].iter().enumerate() {
        let x_index = (x + d_x).clamp(0, BIOME_INDEX_SIZE as isize) as usize;
        let y_index = (y + d_y).clamp(0, BIOME_INDEX_SIZE as isize) as usize;
        let biome = BIOME_GRID[x_index][y_index];
        biomes[i] = biome;
    }

    biomes
}

pub fn blend(
    coord: [i64; 2],
    noise: &Noise,
    biomes: [Biomes; 4],
    blending: [f64; 4],
) -> i64 {
    let heights: Vec<f64> = biomes
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.get().height(coord, noise) as f64)
        .collect();

    let height = heights[0] * blending[0] + heights[1] * blending[1] + heights[2] * blending[2];
    let height = height as i64;

    height
}
```

This works well in some cases, in the other it fails completely.

I am unsure, if 2 neighbours are enough and how to properly get the `blend` values.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for [bilinear blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) you would use four points. If I understand your code correctly that would be the four height maps for each biome.
You then [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) across one axis (e.g. humidity) for the two pairs with the same other axis, and then lerp the two blended values again with the other axis (e.g. temperature).